# Visualization issue of a simple GUI in Java

Tags: java, jframe

I did a very simple GUI in Java but when I run the program, the GUI acts wierd!

As soon as I run the application: the GUI shows like this:

[image]

Once I simply minimize it and get it back up, it shows fine, like this:

[image]

This is the very simple code:

```
public class Prova2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("A Simple GUI");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(650, 120);
    frame.setLocation(430, 100);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Select one of the possible choices and click OK");;
    lbl.setVisible(true);   
    panel.add(lbl);

    String[] choices = { "CHOICE 1","CHOICE 2", "CHOICE 3","CHOICE 4","CHOICE 5","CHOICE 6"};
    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);
    cb.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(cb);

    JButton btn = new JButton("OK");
    panel.add(btn);
  }
}
```

What am I missing in order to show the GUI fine (with all its element displayed) as soon as I run the application?

It's annoying having to necessarily minimize or resize the window in order to show the GUI properly!

Comment: Try calling `frame.setVisible(true);` as last line. It might help

Comment: It worked, thank you! 

How is it that I cannot mark your help as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and the problem is you are setting the visibility on `true` before you create the items inside your  `JFrame`. So just cut the `frame.setVisible(true);` and paste it as the last line of the constructor.

also I see you aren't using a layout manager which is heavy recommended. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use layout manager
2. Follow a main Swing Toolkit principle: all UI should be manipulated and started on EDT thread ( UI thread ). Here is a very good explanation http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/12/06/unwritten-rule-of-working-with-swings-edt.html